# Enumerating lots of iSCSI volumes. Very slow. Having issues with programmatically getting disk number

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, iscsi

I am currently writing some orchestration software for Hyper-V 2012 R2.

The orchestration platform as a whole also talks to other Hypervisors, like Xen. 
I am in the process of introducing new SAN storage and, due to some desirable features that exist at a storage level, I want to use a LUN-to-VM mapping on all Hypervisors.

I am having real issues with managing this volume of iSCSI connections on Windows. But not in the way I thought I would...

I had heard that there were scaling issues with Windows and ‘lots of LUNs’, but I wanted to check for myself. I am seeing none of the issues other people have mentioned. 
For instance, I can enumerate 500+ LUNs via diskpart in a second. I can list all connected disks with ‘get-disk’, in under a second, the issue comes from iSCSI scaling itself.

If anyone has a moment to read on, perhaps they could shed some light on why...

I have no issue programmatically connecting to the iSCSI targets, but I seem to have real issues when I start trying to get session information (which I need to get other information).

i.e. There seems to be no way to specify which disk number\address an iSCSI target receives at the point it is connected (unless i'm mistaken). I can work backwards from the IQN via WMI, via a call to

```
MSiSCSIInitiator_SessionClass
```

When you start talking about 100+ connected volumes, a call to this class can sometimes take over 10 minutes to return. If I test it via Powerhell with something like:

```
$query =  "Select * from MSiSCSIInitiator_SessionClass Where TargetName='$iqn'"
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\WMI"  -Query $query
```

...you can see it get stuck midway through enumerating the volumes. It will pause. 
I haven’t run the exact numbers, but every additional volume seems to put about 3-4 (or more) seconds on the total time a query takes to return.

It gets a bit weirder. Windows 2012 has some built in iSCSI commands. I can get a connected iSCSI target object in under a second with

```
Get-IscsiTarget –nodeaddress blah
```

I can get an iSCSI connection object using

```
$iscsi_target_object | Get-IsciConnection
```

... all in in under a second. These must be related to iSCSI session inforation in some way.

A call, no matter how I package it, to Get-IscsiSession takes about 10 minutes to return.

The Hyper-VM manager GUI is also terribly slow when opening the settings page for a VM, presumably because it is enumerating possible pass-through disks via their iSCSI session. This also takes around ten minutes.

A query to Msvm_DiskDrive in root/virtualisation also takes an age to return..

Again, diskpart, Get-Disk etc all return in seconds. I can refresh all iSCSI targets on the system in about a minute with 500+ targets. I thought that was going to be the hard bit.

So, I have two questions.

First all, does this sound right? Is there anything at all I doing something that might 
impact the speed at which WMI calls are returned? Can I speed WMI up at all?

Secondly, can anyone think of any other way – other than the MSiSCSIInitiator_SessionClass – that I could derive a disk number from an IQN? This might solve the bulk of my problems. Perhaps there other routes to this information i might have missed.

Cheers.

Comment: FYI, WMI is simply a layer on top of other services. WMI doesn't really do anything in and of itself, so you can't really "speed up WMI." The providers that are registered with WMI are what provide dynamic data, and expose that data through the standard WMI (CIM) interface.

Comment: Why C# tag? Looks like Powershell.

Comment: It's a C# application but I have some hosted Powershell too. If there were easier ways to the data via C# i'd take that.

Comment: [Get-WmiCustom](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/7bae3d39-c6c3-4a8a-8c98-1b8851bd2cbe) lets you specify a shorter timeout with gwmi.